# Flip tooltips depending on quadrant

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple tooltips which appear on hover and follow the mouse cursor.

Each trigger is situated in a different quadrant of the viewport.

```js
// The following will find the tooltips, and then adds an event on mousemove that allows the position of the tooltip to follow the cursor's location

var tooltip = document.querySelectorAll('.z-tooltip');

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', fn, false);

  function fn(e) {
      for (var i=tooltip.length; i--;) {
          tooltip[i].style.left = e.clientX + 10 + 'px';
          tooltip[i].style.top = e.clientY + 10 + 'px';
      }
  }
```

```css
/* Hide and show the tooltip */

.z-trigger:hover .z-tooltip {
    display: block;
}

.z-tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid;
}

/* Position the links in different quadrants of the viewport for example's sake */

.z-top-left {
position: absolute;
top: 25%;
left: 25%
}

.z-top-right {
position: absolute;
top: 25%;
right: 25%
}

.z-bottom-left {
position: absolute;
bottom: 25%;
left: 25%
}

.z-bottom-right {
position: absolute;
bottom: 25%;
right: 25%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="z-top-left z-trigger">
  Top left quadrant 
    <span class="z-tooltip">
      I want this to display to the bottom right of the cursor - it does :)
    </span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="z-top-right z-trigger">
  Top right quadrant 
    <span class="z-tooltip">
      I want this to display to the bottom left of the cursor - it doesn't :(
    </span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="z-bottom-left z-trigger">
  Bottom left quadrant
    <span class="z-tooltip">
      I want this to display to the top right of the cursor - it doesn't :(
    </span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="z-bottom-right z-trigger">
  Bottom right quadrant
    <span class="z-tooltip">
      I want this to display to the top left of the cursor - it doesn't :(
    </span>
</a>
```

What I would like javascript (or jQuery) to do is to:

- Detect which quadrant of the screen the 'trigger' is situated within
- Make the resulting hover tooltip appear next to the cursor - but pointing **away** from the quadrant in which the trigger lies

For example if I hover over one of these trigger elements and it happens to be anywhere within the **top right** quadrant of the viewport, I want the tooltip to appear **to the bottom and to the left of** the cursor position.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: I would recommend to adjust the `fn(e) { ... }`: check the `classList` of the `tooltip[i].parentNode` and include the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` of the `tooltip` in the calculation

Comment: @AndreasSchrottenbaum thanks for the insight. Could you please show me how to execute this in a fiddle/codepen?

Comment: https://codepen.io/andreasschrottenbaum/pen/OJXroZg this should be a point to start

Comment: @AndreasSchrottenbaum Thanks for putting that together. I don't think your approach will work however as it seems to rely on finding the actual classes 'z-top-left' etc. in the DOM. 

My tooltips won't be hard coded in like this, and I'd like to find a method where javascript/jQuery works out which quadrant the tooltip is in, based on something like window.InnerWidth for example

Comment: https://codepen.io/andreasschrottenbaum/pen/xxOmaeb here you go. you need to combine it by yourself

Comment: @AndreasSchrottenbaum I managed to solve my case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64812793/getting-javascript-to-select-all-elements-not-just-the-first-one?noredirect=1#comment114592793_64812793

Thanks for your help, hope someone else in need sees this.