# Getting javascript to select ALL elements, not just the first one

Tags: javascript

I have copied a script which does some cool stuff with a floating tooltip (sticks to cursor and flips depending on which quadrant of the viewport it is in, to keep it visible at all times etc).

**Everything works fine for the first element found**. But it doesn't work on the second element, or any elements after that either.

```js
// I want to select ALL divs with the class 'z-tooltip' but it only seems to select the first one
var tooltip = this.document.getElementsByClassName("z-tooltip")[0];

window.onmousemove = function(ev) {

  var leftPixelSpace = ev.clientX;
  var rightPixelSpace = this.innerWidth - leftPixelSpace; 
  var topPixelSpace = ev.clientY;
  var bottomPixelSpace = this.innerHeight - topPixelSpace;

  var tooltipPosX = leftPixelSpace > rightPixelSpace ? leftPixelSpace  - tooltip.offsetWidth : leftPixelSpace;
  var tooltipPosY = topPixelSpace > bottomPixelSpace ? topPixelSpace - tooltip.offsetHeight : topPixelSpace;
  
  // I want to apply these styles to ALL divs with the class 'z-tooltip', but again, it only seems to work on the first div...
  tooltip.style.left = tooltipPosX+"px";
  tooltip.style.top = tooltipPosY+"px";
};
```

```css
.z-tooltip {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color : lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="z-tooltip">floating tooltip</div>

<div class="z-tooltip">floating tooltip</div>

<div class="z-tooltip">floating tooltip</div>
```

I did some reading and I have seen that `getElementsByClassName("z-tooltip")[0]` returns them as an HTML collection, which is not what I want.

Instead I should use `querySelectorAll('.z-tooltip)` which would select all elements with the class `z-tooltip`. However when I use this none of the script works any more :(

Furthermore, I want to be able to apply a style (see end of snippet) to ALL elements with the class `z-tooltip`. I know that to do this I will need to 'loop through' all of them and apply the style. Here's what I've tried so far but it doesn't work:

```
for (var i=tooltip.length; i--;) {

tooltip.style.left = tooltipPosX+"px";
tooltip.style.top = tooltipPosY+"px";

}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You just need to take the `[0]` off and loop over them...

Comment: your code only works for 1st element. var tooltip = this.document.getElementsByClassName("z-tooltip")[0]; Remove[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// I want to select ALL divs with the class 'z-tooltip' but it only seems to select the first one
var tooltip = this.document.getElementsByClassName("z-tooltip");

window.onmousemove = function(ev) {

  var leftPixelSpace = ev.clientX;
  var rightPixelSpace = this.innerWidth - leftPixelSpace; 
  var topPixelSpace = ev.clientY;
  var bottomPixelSpace = this.innerHeight - topPixelSpace;
  
  // I want to apply these styles to ALL divs with the class 'z-tooltip', but again, it only seems to work on the first div...
  [...tooltip].forEach(tooltip => {
    let tooltipPosX = leftPixelSpace > rightPixelSpace ? leftPixelSpace  - tooltip.offsetWidth : leftPixelSpace;
    let tooltipPosY = topPixelSpace > bottomPixelSpace ? topPixelSpace - tooltip.offsetHeight : topPixelSpace;

    tooltip.style.left = tooltipPosX+"px";
    tooltip.style.top = tooltipPosY+"px";
  });
};
```

```css
.z-tooltip {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color : lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="z-tooltip">floating tooltip</div>

<div class="z-tooltip">floating tooltip</div>

<div class="z-tooltip">floating tooltip</div>
```

- Took the `[0]` off to get all the tooltips
- Change the logic to `[...tooltip].forEach` to convert the result to an array that could then be looped over

Comment: Hey @taplar, this selects all of the tooltips but the main function no longer works now (flipping the tooltips depending on how much available space there is).

Comment: @Teebling I missed that the `tooltip` was being used to compute the tooltipPosX and Y.  Those just needed to be moved into the loop.

Comment: My man! Thanks so much for your help it works now :)